# DBMS_SCHEDULER running 10 instance of the same job

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to have a single scheduler that will run multiple (from 4 to 10) jobs at the same time.

I know this is doable if I just make multiple dbms_scheduler of the same job, (job1, job2....) . but this seems wrong, and it's also a lot of maintainance down the road. but this is the only way i found online.

is there another way of accomplish this task, where i can set up a single dbms_scheduler, and set it up to run multiple instance at the same time?

Comment: It is the wrong place to ask. Try [dba.se]

Comment: But I would assume that it is not possible, because every job has own session, process etc. Also every job can be managed through `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Your idea will require whole new level of abstraction for jobs.

Comment: You can also create a common schedule with `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE` and then all jobs will use this schedule. This will greatly reduce the work for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can do this. You write a controller procedure that you manually schedule once on a repeating schedule. That controller procedure then creates multiple one-off child jobs as needed. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE controller_proc
AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec_control IN (SELECT * FROM control_table)
  LOOP
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'JOB$'||rec_control.identifier,
                              job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                              auto_drop => TRUE,
                              enabled => TRUE,
                              job_action => '
BEGIN
  child_proc(in_identifier => '''||rec_control.identifier||''');
END;
                              ');

  END LOOP;
END;  
/
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'JOB$CONTROLLER_PROC',
                            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                            job_action => 'CONTROLLER_PROC',
                            repeat_interval => 'TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1+(12/24)',
                            enabled => TRUE);
END;  
/
```

child_proc would contain your actual workload. [I got lazy and used a PL/SQL block to do this, but it'd be better if this will operate at high frequency to define a program and argument and then use the STORED_PROCEDURE job type and set the argument value... but this'll work just fine.]

Comment: OK this makes sense. 

so instead of having 1 dbms_scheduler for the job, I would have a parent scheduler, that spawns (one time) child for each job. 

and if any of the job got stuck, i would just kill the child procedure, instead of the parent.

Thanks a ton! will try this out;

Comment: That's the idea. And of course to make it robust you'd want a logging table where each child logs its status/result. And if the # of children becomes too great that is causes a performance/resource issue, you can add job counting and waiting (dbms_lock.sleep) into the loop within the controller proc to ensure that the # of jobs doesn't get too high.

Comment: You mixed [Scheduler Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.htm) with (legacy) [Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_JOB.html). The `repeat_interval` must be like `'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=04,05,06,07,08,09,10'` for example.

Comment: @Wernfried, that's not true. Modern scheduler jobs accept both formats. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: @PaulW You are right, despite it is quite hidden in the documentation. However when you use  `CREATE_WINDOW` or `CREATE_SCHEDULE` then you must use the [calendaring syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-73622B78-EFF4-4D06-92F5-E358AB2D58F3).

Comment: Yes, I know, but in my answer to OP, as is the case with the majority of jobs folks write, such complexity was not needed. A simple create_job suffices. In terms of preference, since we work with date arithmetic every day with the Oracle date datatype, it seems sensible to employ the same when creating jobs rather than employing a totally foreign syntax that is used for nothing else. But as I said, to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple jobs, each using the same Scheduler schedule, or if your job is calling a stored procedure you could look at using Scheduler Job Chains to run the same procedure in parallel, as described [here](https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/06/16/parallel-execution-of-pl-sql-procedures/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362298/run-procedures-in-parallel-oracle-pl-sql/62368447#62368447).

In essence you would then create a job chain with multiple steps that run in parallel, each calling an instance of the stored procedure (could be same or different procedures). The entire job would run on one schedule with one log. You could add or remove chain steps to increase or decrease the degree of parallelism.

Comment: Thanks pmdba.

i haven't used job_chain before, so it's definitely worth looking into it. 

after looking at the example, is it true that if any of the job within the job chain is having issue, and takes forever to finish, it will prevent the main job from finishing ? assuming that's the case, this might not work for my case.